# Unity - GUI editor, loading level into "scene" window

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the GUI editor in Unity, I'm confident I can do something good with it but not everything, i.e. placing lights and so on.
What I really would like to do is to create the start of my levels with my own editor and the finishing up with Unity's classic way of building levels, the scene window.

Is it possible for me to load my level in the scene view from a file now?
Thanks for your time, much appreciated ;)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufVNw.png (exitting game mode destroys all changes done so I can load my level in, but ONLY in playmode)

Comment: Code-based GUI will only show up while playing. It's recommended that you use Unity 5's new(ish) GUI system using the canvas. [citation needed]

Comment: I thought the canvas was only in playmode too? Right now, I'm creating Windows with EditorWindow herited scripts so I found a way. But if I could use Canvas like you mention it'd be much faster!

Comment: no, canvas is in both the scene view and game view all the time, as can been seen in the scene view on the right in that picture (The "Orbs: 2/15" text appears to be a text element in a Unity 5 canvas)